# Custom fonts in iOS with Phonegap Canvas

Tags: ios, xcode, html, cordova

I'm trying to make a custom font work in Phonegap under iOS.
I followed several tutorials and read all the related question on Stack Overflow and I still can't get it right, even if I double checked everything.

This is the font: http://www.dafont.com/m04fatal-fury.font (**the black version**)

Step I've taken

Add your custom font files into your project using Xcode as a resource
Add a key to your Info.plist file called UIAppFonts.
Make this key an array
For each font you have, enter the full name of your font file (including the extension) as items to the UIAppFonts array
Save Info.plist
Now in your application you can simply call [UIFont fontWithName:@"CustomFontName" size:12] to get the custom font to use with your UILabels and UITextViews, etc…

1. Added font into resource folder m04b.ttf
2. Added UIAppFonts array. [0] => 'm04b.ttf'
3. Checked that the actual font file was in the build phase resources
4. ctx.font = '16px M04_FATAL FURY BLACK';

Didn't work.

Tried the postscript name M04_FATAL-FURY-BLACK still no luck. I'm completely lost here I really don't know what to do to debug this error.

Thank you very much for any help. What could be the problem? What could I do to check if everything is getting loaded?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>m04b.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    .....
```

Comment: May you add `Info.plist` related sections?

Comment: If you add a `for (NSString *font in [UIFont familyNames]) { NSLog(@"%@", font); }` somewhere in the app, can you see the font showing up? (I see an entry "M04_FATAL FURY")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. I can almost guarantee you're just misspelling the name wrong by a space or dash or something. Put this into `viewDidLoad` and just search for something similar to your name (the common name.. not the .ttf name).

```
for (NSString *name in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    NSLog(@"Family name : %@", name);
    for (NSString *font in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:name]) {
        NSLog(@"Font name : %@", font);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used CSS font-face and it works pretty well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@font-face.

Just added the fonts under the www/css and included the font-face with proper paths.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the font in the .plist file under the "Fonts provided by application" key, which is proposed when you enter your key name, instead of "UIAppFonts".

Comment: They are one and the same. `UIAppFonts` is the actual "raw" key name, while `Fonts provided by application` is simply a more friendly description of that key, which incorporates the purpose. If you right-click in the editor for a property list, you can toggle between raw and display names using the `Show Raw Keys/Values` menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Download the font and put it somewhere in your www folder.

in your css file add the following.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: customFontExample;
    src: url('/fonts/AveriaGruesaLibre-Regular.ttf'); 
}
```

src is the path to where you have downloaded the font. after this you can give your elements the custom font by using the name "customFontExample" like this

```
h1{
font-family: customFontExample;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To all the folks out here, if you need the @font-face stuff, you're doing it wrong.

Once you have your font available with UIFont in your app, it's also available in any UIWebView you create, you just have to specify your font-family css property the right way.

For example

```
.customfont { font-family: 'M04_FATAL-FURY-BLACK'; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the "Fonts provided by application" / Resources embed method, and I found that you also have to specify the .ttf extension in your application.

But in a canvas context I could not get the size right, the font was very small.

So in my experience this doesn't work well and you have to fall back to the html @font-face method, which is a pain because it's very hard to know when the font is loaded and ready for use...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The issue was that I added the font to the resources folder through the finder. I noticed that the font although in the folder wasn't appearing in Xcode. I added then the file through xcode and it worked!